# How to create Bootstrap columns without padding/margin that are half the screen-size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I am trying to achieve a similar effect to the one from this website:
http://planilandia.com/index(en).html

They are 50% of the screen plus there is no border, margin or padding between them. I've tried to achieve that but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.movies-player div {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.home-video {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
}
::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
.row-no-padding {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-top:0 !important;
    padding-bottom:0 !imprtant;
    border:0!important;
}
.section-movies {
    width:100%;
}
.section-movies .row {  
    text-align:center;
}
.section-movies .row div video {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container section-movies">
    <div class="row row-no-padding movies-player">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <video controls class="home-video" poster="img/movies/about-us-poster.jpg" loop="true" preload="auto">
                <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <video controls class="home-video" poster="img/movies/projects-poster.jpg" loop="true" preload="auto">
                <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>                        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-no-padding movies-player">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <video controls class="home-video" poster="img/movies/contact-poster.jpg" loop="true" preload="auto">
                <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <video controls class="home-video" poster="img/movies/made-by-us-poster.jpg" loop="true" preload="auto">
                <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
<! --/container -->
```

This is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uceder23/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. There's no styling for your .col-lg-6 class. That's half of your rows. It should be 50%;
So,

```
.col-lg-6 {
width: 50%;
float:left;
}
```

Then, the video element should be a block so you could get rid of the annyong lower whitespace (acts like an img element here if its not a block).
Everything set, although there are things I don't know from your original code.

Forked here

http://jsfiddle.net/7kb9nfhn/2/

Comment: Thanks! one more question - as you will see there is a small (about 1px) line between columns. its a fault of bootstrap, videos or what?

Comment: I don't see the pixel from here. It takes time to achieve exactly what you need from scratch. And there comes debugging. If you want it to look like your example, why don't you try replicating it? Is just adding the right attributes to your css classes and IDs.
And we don't have your whole site, just some css and html. It might be a bug as well.